# FCKeditor URL insertion does not display page list

Tags: liferay, fckeditor

In my Liferay installation, when I am editing a page (Web Content) and trying to insert an URL, only explicit URLs are allowed. So, to make link to an existing Liferay page, I need to copy paste it's URL from browser.

(picture)

[image]

Is this by design?

Is it possible to present drop down list of currently existing pages like it is done in page creation portlet?

(picture of page creation portlet)

[image]

Comment: Its by design itself. FCKEditor has nothing to do with Liferay's Page URLs. FCKeditor is just we can say editor being used to make web-content creation/view in well manner.

Comment: It could be modded since it is opensource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to click 'Browse server' button in link dialog . Then in appeared window select 'Page' option from 'Resource Type' selectbox and then (on the right side of the window) you can navigate to required page by selecting a site and particular pages. URL of selected page will be used in FCKEditor.